# How to search for greek text using lunr.js

Tags: lunrjs

I am developing a multilanguage site using hugo cms with english and greek translations and I use lunr.js to search contents. I found that lunr does not support greek (lunr-languages - npm) and I would like to ask if there is a work around to search for greek text and if yes what are the steps?

Also I noticed that lunr is only indexing for english content. How can we also index the greek content?

Thank you.

The following code does not index the greek content althought there is a languages.toml with english and greek config.

**search-index.hmtl**

```
<script>
    window.store = {
        // Blog
        {{ range where .Site.RegularPages "Type" "blog" }}
        "{{ .Permalink }}": {
            "title": "{{ .Title  }}",
            "tags": [{{ range .Params.Tags }}"{{ . }}",{{ end }}],
            "content": {{ .Content | plainify }},
            "url": "{{ .Permalink }}"
        },
        {{ end }}
</script>
<script src="/js/lunr.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/search.js"></script>
```

**search.js**

```
function displayResults (results, store) {
  const searchResults = document.getElementById('results');
  if (results.length) {
  let resultList = ''
  for (const n in results) {
      const item = store[results[n].ref]
      resultList += `
          <li>
              <h6>
                  <a href="${item.url}">${item.title}</a>
              </h6>
              <p>${item.content.substring(0, 150)}...</p>
              <p>${item.tags}</p>
          </li>
      `;
  }
  searchResults.innerHTML = resultList
  } else {
  searchResults.innerHTML = 'No results found.'
}
}

const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
const query = params.get('query')

if (query) {
  document.getElementById('search-input').setAttribute('value', query)
  const idx = lunr(function () {
      this.ref('id')
      this.field('title', {
          boost: 15
      })
      this.field('tags')
      this.field('content', {
          boost: 10
      })

      // provide search index data to lunr function / idx
      for (const key in window.store) {
          this.add({
          id: key,
          title: window.store[key].title,
          tags: window.store[key].category,
          content: window.store[key].content
          })
      }
})
console.log(window.store);
const results = idx.search(query)
displayResults(results, window.store)
}
```